# ¿En qué desginación de tipo de variables me estoy equivocando?

Tags: array, vba, matrices

Estoy intentando hacer una función que calcule el valor de mercado de un swap, hago uso de "arreglos" y de asignación de valores por "posiciones de arreglos", pero no sé en qué parte es la que me estoy equivocando en mi asignación de tipo de variables.

Disclaimer: Apenas estoy empezando en VBA, es por esto que quizá la respuesta sea muy lógica pero espero puedan ayudarme.

```
Public Function VMerc(hoy As Date, _
                  notional As Double, _
                  vencimiento As Date, _

                  finCupAct As Date, _
                  periodo As Integer, _
                  tFija As Double, _
                  tcero As Range) As Double

Dim Pc, j, dias As Integer
Dim fd, tfwd As Double
Dim PagoFijo, calc, PagoVariable As Double

Pc = ((vencimiento - finCupAct) / periodo)+1 'Esto calcula el límite de mis ciclos for'

ReDim dias(Pc)
```

Esto me lo sugirió un compañero para definir el tamaño límite de mi "arreglo" dias(), aunque me sale un error que dice "Se esperaba una matriz"

```
'Obtenemos los días (un arreglo con días definidos)'
For i = 1 To Pc 
  dias(i) = finCupAct - hoy
  finCupAct = finCupAct + periodo
Next i

'Calculamos su factor de descuento y tasa forward'
For i = 1 To Pc
  fd(i) = 1 / (1 + tcero(dias(i)) * dias(i) / 360)
   If i = 1 Then
     tfwd(i) = tcero(i)
   Else
     tfwd(i) = (((1 + tcero(dias(i)) * dias(i) / 360) / (1 + tcero(dias(i - 1)) * dias(i - 1) / 360)) - 1) * (360 / periodo)
Next i
```

Para la variable tcero(), estoy intentando ocupar la posición dada por el entero guardado en dias(), aquí quizá también tengo un error.

```
PagoFijo = nocional * tFija * periodo / 360 * Pc
PagoVariable = 0

For i = 1 To Pc
  calc = nocional * tfwd(i) * periodo / 360
  PagoVariable = PagoVariable + calc
Next i

VMerc = PagoVariable - PagoFijo

End Function
```

Espero me puedan apoyar en ver mis errores, ¡gracias! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Una matriz es un conjunto de valores, que se denomina elementos, que
>   se relacionan lógicamente entre sí. Por ejemplo, una matriz puede
>   consistir en el número de alumnos de cada curso en una escuela
>   primaria; cada elemento de la matriz es el número de alumnos de un
>   curso único. De forma similar, una matriz puede constar de las
>   calificaciones de un estudiante de una clase; cada elemento de la
>   matriz es una puntuación de una sola.

En VBA, para definir una variable de tipo matriz, se utiliza la siguiente notación:

```
Dim MiMatriz(4) as Double
```

Arriba he definido una matriz unidimensional de 5 filas, que se llama MiMatriz. Fíjate bien en que puse paréntesis al final, y dentro de los paréntesis, la cantidad de filas. Son 5 filas, porque aunque yo pusiera un 4, la primera fila siempre es el 0, así que la matriz tiene la fila 0,1,2,3,4. En total, 5.

Para acceder a un valor concreto, simplemente escribiríamos:

```
MiMatriz(1) 'devuelve el valor de la fila 1
MiMatriz (3) 'devuelve el valor de la fila 3
```

A veces por el código (parece tu caso) no sabes el tamaño que va a tener tu matriz, en esos casos la defines sin tamaño. Por ejemplo:

```
Dim dias() as Integer 'Esta matriz no sabemos cuántas filas tendrá
```

Aquí VBA sabe que dias es una matriz, pero no sabe su tamaño. Por ello, cuando sepas el tamaño que va a tener, es necesario usar Redim, es decir, "redimensionamos". Aplicado a tu ejemplo, es la línea de código de tu amigo:

```
Redim dias(Pc) as Integer
```

VBA redimensionará el tamaño de la matriz dias según en valor de PC.

Tu código te da el error "Se Esperaba una matriz" porque tu variable no está definida como una matriz, sino como una variable estándar.

Prueba a definirte todas tus variables "normales" por un lado, y luego tus variables usando la notación que te he comentado (lo de los paréntesis).

No quiero alargar mucho mi respuesta por no desviarme del tema, pero que sepas que las matrices dan mucho juego, pueden ser de varias dimensiones (en tu caso, unidimensionales, es decir, de 1 sola columna, te será suficiente), pero te dejo algún enlace por si quieres profundizar en el tema. Merece MUCHO la pena aprender a manejar matrices.

[Matrices en VBA](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/)

Espero que te sirva esta respuesta.